# Is it possible to use vimgrep with file paths from a file?

Tags: search, vimgrep

I have a quite large directory that I frequently need to search through for specific lines. Currently I simply use the built in `grep`:

```
:vim "search" **/*.cpp | cw
```

The problem is that going through all files in the repo takes ~1-2 minutes normally due to having to the OS globbing all files, and it really slows down development. On the command line, I can store file paths in a file and use them without having to reindex everytime:

```
> find . -type f -name "*.cpp" > cppfiles
> grep "search" `cat cppfiles` # possible to reuse the index files for multiple searches. Goes _a lot_ faster.
```

Can I do the same thing with the built-in search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On unix like systems, you can use backticks directly in the vimgrep command (in any command that takes file names)

```
:vimgrep "search" `cat cppfiles` | cw
```

There is vim-only way by loading the cpp files into the argument list:

```
:%argdelete
:argadd **/*.cpp
:vimgrep "search" ##
```

`##` is a special notation for the argument list.

Comment: I thought I tried this, but alas. However, it turns out that this is still comparatively slow -- I think I'll just resort to grepping in the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: You may also want to use vim's `:grep` instead, which uses `grepprg` (by default the program "grep").  It is generally faster than `:vimgrep`.

Comment: Oh wow -- `:grep` is a lot faster! Do you know how I can use it in a good fashion? Currently I use the command `command! -nargs Grep :vimgrep <q-args> 'cat hcppfiles' | cw`, but changing it to `grep` does not display the search results as neatly (I can't jump to the different files, for example).

Comment: Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/). I also would recommend use `:grep`. Even better use a faster grep, like [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). However it looks like you are using C/C++ which means you can use ctags and/or cscope. Which will be a precomputed database so can jump to definitions instantly. See `:h tags` & `:h cscope`.

Comment: @pingul It should work by default.  After `:grep` you should see the entries in the quickfix window (doing `:cw`) just like with vimgrep.  Make sure `grepprg` and `grepformat` are set sensibly (defaults ought to work).

Comment: I'd give you 5 upvotes if I could -- this improves my vim usage greatly! Thanks!